# React fullcalendar change selectAllow behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm working on a calendar view that will allow user to make a reservation for a specific day and time. My problem is current behaviour of selectAllow function.
I want to restrict the user to be able to select max 2 slots (60 minutes in that example), and if he selects more, the selection should stay at the maximum possible time range, instead of disappearing and showing the not-allowed cursor. Would that be possible?

A fiddle for better visualization:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-forked-vm3k5y

Try to select more than 2 slots in a single day.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't change that without rewriting the source code of fullCalendar

Comment: Do you have any idea of a workaround maybe without using selectAllow function?

Comment: No. That's just the way the selections UX is designed.